# Minha página dá "refresh" mesmo fazendo a requisição via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Minha página dá "refresh" mesmo fazendo a requisição via ajax...

````
    try{
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (IEAtual){
        try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(IEAntigo){
            try{
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(falha){
                request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request)
        alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
    else
        return request;
}

function getDados() {
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
            var cracha  = document.getElementById("tst").value;
            var result = document.getElementById("Resultado");

            var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

            xmlreq.open("GET", "index.php?tst=" + cracha, true);

            xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlreq.readyState == 4){
                    if (xmlreq.status == 200){
                        result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
                        preencheCampos();
                    }else{
                        result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlreq.send(null);
        }
}

function preencheCampos() {
    v1 = document.getElementById("v1").value;
    v2 = document.getElementById("v2").value;

    document.getElementById("nome").value = v1;
    document.getElementById("setor").value = v2;
}```


Obs.: o arquivo index.php está com include do arquivo que puxa os dados do banco. Consigo pegar o valor, mas pelos meus testes, faz refresh do mesmo jeito.
````

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar o refresh é preciso chamar o método preventDefault().

```
event.preventDefault()
```